# mod_sed - apache+sed - problems with backslash

Tags: apache-http-server, sed

I have just started using sed and are having a problem when using sed from Apache mod_seq. 
The task is to change a web service post to a file upload post. Content-Type has already been changed using mod_headers and the task here is to change request body.

Request body:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/msg/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/core/1.0"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns:test>Hello World</ns:test></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

1) ok test with sed from command prompt:

```
sed "s/^.*$/--AaB03x\nContent-disposition: form-data; name=\"xmlfile\"; filename=\"myfile.xml\"\nContent-Type: text\/xml\n\n&\n--AaB03x--\n/" request.xml
```

Output as expected with newlines:

```
--AaB03x
Content-disposition: form-data; name="xmlfile"; filename="myfile.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/msg/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/core/1.0"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns:test>Hello World</ns:test></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--AaB03x--
```

2) Sed call with Apache mod_sed:

```
InputSed "s/^.*$/--AaB03x\nContent-disposition: form-data; name=\"xmlfile\"; filename=\"myfile.xml\"\nContent-Type: text\/xml\n\n&\n--AaB03x--\n/"
```

Output from mod_sed when request enters my web app. Note "n" instead of newline.

```
--AaB03xnContent-disposition: form-data; name="xmlfile"; filename="myfile.xml"nContent-Type: text/xmlnn<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/msg/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://tracx.de/pkp/interfaces/core/1.0"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns:test>monday</ns:test></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>n--AaB03x--n
```

I have tried with '' and "" i InputSed command. And tried with 1, 2, 3 and 4 backspaces before my control characters (\r and \n). It looks like Apache or mod_sed are ignoring backslash character.
Anyone that known if there is some special problems with mod_sed and backslash?

Comment: I am also having this problem. Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ugly workaround tested on Ubuntu Apache/2.4.18, using the supported subset of sed:

```
$ cat tmp
line3
$ sed "h;s/.*/line1/;p;s/.*/line2/;G;p;s/.*/line4/" tmp
line1
line2
line3
line4
$ cat week
sunday
wednesday
friday
$ sed "2{h;s/.*/monday/;p;s/.*/tuesday/;G;p;s/.*/thursday/;n;p;s/.*/saturday/;}" week
sunday
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
saturday
```

```
these work too as \n is still recognised in search string
"G;H;g;s/\n/line1&line2&/;s/\n$/&line4/"
"2{G;H;g;s/\n/monday&tuesday&/;s/\n$/&thursday/;n;p;s/.*/saturday/;}"
```

```
$ #sudo a2enmod sed
$ #apache2.conf
<Location /txt/>
    AddOutputFilter Sed txt
    OutputSed "G;H;g;s/\n/line1&line2&/;s/\n$/&line4/"
</Location>
$ service apache2 reload
$ wget localhost/txt/tmp.txt -qO -
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

```
$ #sudo a2enmod ext_filter
$ #apache2.conf
ExtFilterDefine external_sed mode=output intype=text/plain cmd="/bin/sed :0;N;$!b0;s/\\n//g"
<Location /txt/>
    SetOutputFilter external_sed
</Location>
$ service apache2 reload
$ wget localhost/txt/week.txt -qO -
sundaywednesdayfriday
```

See also: [#1](http://capttofu.tripod.com/wordpress_bak/), [#2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_ext_filter.html)

Comment: escape sequences, append, insert, exchange are (seemingly) all unrecognised by apache mod_sed

Comment: yes - actually i wanted to remove all \n in the request body. But I couldnt, because just replaces "n" (backslash removed) or "\\n" (-> replaces nothing, because sed needs \n).

Comment: I checked already - its the same problem. Its even the same problem with an external filter file (-f) for sed.

Comment: That's puzzling. I've actually tested and tried my answer before posting. You should post the offending codes & settings in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a single line of text with multiple lines of text you could try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576031/substituting-a-single-line-with-multiple-lines-of-text).

I have no experience with mod_sed, but the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_sed.html) states:

> mod_sed can be used as an input or output filter. mod_sed is a content
>   filter, which means that it cannot be used to modify client or server
>   http headers.

mod_headers may be more suitable for what you want to do.